# Grouping metadatas into one

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox

I want to have some custom metadatas for my custom post type. I know how to add the metadatas one by one, but I need to some of them together, considered as a single metadata. 
For example lets assume that you have a barbershop custom post type. You want to add services that this barbershop offers as metadatas. Every service should have title, description and number of likes. Sure you can add this in single metadatas, but how can we manage the situation that the title, description and the number of likes, shown and considered as a single metadata and relate to each other?